# Mobile hotspot cannot be activated because "No internet access"

Tags: networking, windows-10, internet-sharing, wireless-hotspot

Although I have internet connection, network status shows "*no internet access*".

That prevents using **Mobile Hotspot** to share the internet connection because it says "*We can't set up mobile hotspot because your PC doesn't have an Ethernet, WiFi or mobile data connection*".

I do remember that I could enable **Mobile Hotspot** even if network status was showing "no internet access".

Besides, maybe I don't want to share internet connection but I want to use remote desktop? Who cares! Even if there is no internet connection, Mobile Hotspot should be able to share the active ethernet connection, without checking if it has an internet connection or not.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, try to reinstall all the network drivers, and update/upgrade to the latest.

Then it could due to the destroyed user profile, have you try other user, just try to add a new account and try again.

Then if the new account doesn't have any issue on the network status, and it should can use mobile hotspot, try the ways in the link to fix the account that has the issue.

According to **Waseem Patwegar** - [**How to Fix A Corrupt User Profile In Windows 10**](https://www.techbout.com/fix-corrupt-user-profile-windows-10-9139/)

You can refer to the following steps.

1. Right Click on the Windows 10 **Start button** and click on **Run**.
2. Type **regedit** into the search box and press **Enter**.
3. Now, navigate to the following key:
   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList.**
   Once you follow the file path and reach ProfileList, you will see folders starting with **S-1-5**. Each of these folders represents a user profile or a user account created on your computer.
4. Click on each **S-1-5** folder and identify the folder that is related to the user account that you are trying to fix.
5. Once you have identified the right folder, Double Click on the entry “**State**” to launch a pop-up window and change the value to 0.
6. Next, Double Click on the entry “**RefCount**” to launch a popup window and change the value to **0**.
   Note: If you do not have **RefCount**, then you can create a new file by right clicking anywhere on the blank space in the right pane – Click **New** > **DWORD (32 bit**) > type **RefCount** > click on **Enter**.
7. Close **regedit** and **restart** your computer.

Then see if the network status to see if it is fine, and enable Mobile Hotspot.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Created a new user and a new profile, still not working. Also deleted all network adapter drivers, didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Resolution One: You use a hostednetwork if your wireless adapter is capable. (Usually they are capable.)

1.) [Open command prompt](https://techniedges.com/open-command-prompt-windows-10/). Win+X and choose CMD (Admin) OR type in "cmd" or "command prompt" into Windows Search by typing into Start Menu and then right click "Command Prompt" and select "Run As Administrator"

2.) Check if your system is capable run this command: netsh wlan show drivers. Scroll down to Hosted network supported. If it saysYes you are in luck; if No there is no easy alternative and don't continue. You can [Remove CRC SHA](https://techniedges.com/remove-crc-sha-from-context-menu/).

3.) Run the following command to allow and set up your hostednetwork but look below first.

netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=%ssid% key=%pass% keyUsage=persistent
Replace %ssid% with your Wifi or "Hotspot" Name or SSID. E.g. ssid=MyGreatHotspot. Replace %pass% with your Wifi or "Hotspot" Password. It must be 8 characters long at a minimum. E.g. key=strongPasswordsAreWEAK.

4.) After that run the command, netsh wlan start hostednetwork, to start the "Hotspot" broadcast. Right now you can play without internet connection after all devices connect. Remember to check IP addresses of all your individual devices in order to connect to each other. The hotspot's IP Address usually is "192.168.137.1".

If you want to share your internet connection or for further reference, continue on:

5.) Open Run (Win + R) or by searching for Run and enter in ncpa.cpl, then press Enter. A new adapter has shown in the screen it should say something along the lines of "Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter". (Optional if you're OCD, rename that one if its says "L.A.N Connection* 15" or rather to like "Hotspot"). Right click the Internet Connect Source you want to share internet from and choose "Properties." Go to the "Sharing" Tab and checkmark or toggle on "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet Connection." Apply, OK to save changes.